# Can we contribute a new plugin.xml to ExtensionRegistry

Tags: eclipse, registry, osgi, equinox

I have a some additional xml files(containing standard eclipse extensions) that lie outside the bundle. Is there a way that I could contribute the extns/extnpoints in those files to the platform's extension registry?

I tried

```
`Platform.getExtensionRegistry.addContribution(..)`
```

But the method takes a masterToken object, which I dont have access to, and without which it gives me an exception.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to use some internal methods.  Here is what I do:

```
    IExtensionRegistry reg = Platform.getExtensionRegistry();
    Object ut = ((ExtensionRegistry)reg).getTemporaryUserToken();

    IContributor cont = ContributorFactoryOSGi.createContributor(Platform
            .getBundle(editor.getPluginId()));


    if (!reg.addContribution(is, cont, false, null, null, ut))
        Util.impossible("Contribution not added due to error"); //$NON-NLS-1$
```

Comment: Thanks Francis,
I also use something similar. But there are two problems(correct me if I am worng) here:
a) Using temprorary tokens, the contributions won't persist
b) Though my system is an OSGI system, the new contributions are coming from a non-osgi-bundle contributor.
I created the contributor without using ContributorFactoryOSGi somehow, but I am not sure how actually to mix osgi-contributors and non-sogi contributors.

Comment: I'm not sure how to answer any of your concerns.  I would post in the Eclipse Runtime Equinox newsgroup (in eclipse.org - they have a web forums interface as well) and you should be able to get some good help there.

Comment: can you also post the link here, so i could follow up. thanks.